# Can't discover Wifi Network on my MACbook Air upon first reboot after installation

Tags: wireless, networking, macbook, offline

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Macbook Air 2008.

Installation went smoothly and I even managed to install other programs, and to navigate on the internet.

After the first reboot I got a notification: `Network - Disconnected you are now offline.` and from this point on, I can't access any network!

I've read a few posts, but nothing seems to help. I can't connect an ethernet cable (macbook air doesn't have it).  So what should I do?

Thanks in advance,

Antonio

Answer (score 1):

Go into "System Settings", click on "Software Sources" and click on the "Additional Drivers" tab. There should be a Broadcom proprietary driver. Disable it and reboot.

Comment: Didn't work. but tks anyway